# Connection ec2 instance operation timeout error using ssh

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

After creating a new instance,I am trying to access my instance like below:

```
ssh -i private_key.pem root@my_instance_public_domain
```

but the operation is timing out,I have updated the private key file permission using

```
chmod 400
```

and also edited default  security group by adding a new in bound rule,selecting SSH and source Ip as 1.12.34.0/32

but getting port 22: Operation timed out .

what I am missing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing to get this working you'll probably want to set your rule to 0.0.0.0/0.